# With torch or torchvision, how can I resize and crop an image batch, and get both the resizing scales and the new images?

Tags: pytorch, transform, torchvision

I want to transform a batch of images such that they are randomly cropped (with fixed ratio) and resized (scaled). However, I want not only the new images but also a tensor of the scale factors applied to each image. For example, this torchvision transform will do the cropping and resizing I want:

```
scale_transform = torchvision.transforms.RandomResizedCrop(224, scale=(0.08, 1.0), ratio=(1.0, 1.0))
images_scaled = scale_transform(images_original)
```

But I also want to know the scale factors. How might I get those scale factors, or tackle this in a different way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to get ratio of how much cropped part was resized. You can get it by computing xy size of the cropped part and divide it by size you want to get.

```
class MyRandomResizedCrop(object):
    def __init__(self, size, scale, ratio):
        self.t = torchvision.transforms.RandomResizedCrop(size, scale=scale, ratio=ratio)
        self.size = size
        self.scale = scale
        self.ratio = ratio
        
    def __call__(self, sample):
        sample = F.to_pil_image(sample)
        crop_size = self.t.get_params(sample, self.scale, self.ratio)

        x_size = crop_size[2] - crop_size[0]
        y_size = crop_size[3] - crop_size[1]

        x_ratio = sample.size[0] / x_size
        y_ratio = sample.size[1] / y_size
        ratio = (x_ratio, y_ratio) 
        
        output = F.crop(sample, *crop_size)
        output = F.resize(output, self.size)
        
        return ratio, output
```

```
import torchvision
from PIL import Image
import torchvision.transforms.functional as F

size = 244
scale = (0.08, 1.0)
ratio = (1.0, 1.0)

t = MyRandomResizedCrop(size, scale, ratio)

img = torch.rand((3,1024,1024), dtype=torch.float32)

r, img = t(img)
```

Comment: Thanks. That was helpful. Although by reading the RandomResizedCrop source code I realized that is it cropping and resizing all images in the batch in the same manner, which I had not realized when asking my original question. Marking this as the answer but also posting the solution I took before seeing your solution.

Answer (score 0):

After reading the `RandomResizedCrop` source code I realized that is it cropping and resizing all images in the batch in the same manner, which if fine. I'm also in the situation (not specified in my original question) that I know my original images are square, and thus so are the resized/scaled images, since I'm maintaining the height/width ratio. Below is the function I wrote to do what I needed (but with the sample scaling for all images in the batch). I also defined `scale` such that if it is larger than 1.0, the image is cropped and the result appears to be "larger" after resizing. This is the inverse of the `scale` argument of `RandomResizedCrop`.

```
import torchvision.transforms.functional as F
from torchvision.transforms.functional import InterpolationMode

def scale_batch(imgs, max_scale):
    # imgs shape is (batch, channel, height, width) and height must equal width
    assert imgs.shape[2]==imgs.shape[3]
    assert max_scale >= 1.0
    scale_approximate = torch.rand(1).item() * (max_scale-1.0) + 1.0
    hw_original = imgs.shape[2]
    hw_crop = int(round(hw_original / scale_approximate))
    scale_actual = hw_original / hw_crop
    top, left = torch.randint(0, hw_original-hw_crop+1, (2,))
    imgs_scaled = F.resized_crop(imgs, top, left, hw_crop, hw_crop, (hw_original, hw_original), InterpolationMode.BILINEAR)
    return imgs_scaled, scale_actual
```